# Msg error "No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first."

Tags: c#

I try to fill a `datagridview` with the contained (lines) and HEADERS (columns) but to me this error:

> No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.

Data source: SQL server
Really I become tired try please to help me, Thanks firstly..

Comment: If you are tired do go to sleep! This is no way to ask a question. If your DataSource is ineed an sql query the message means that you probably shouldn't have set AutoGenerateColumns to false for your DGV..

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code for you.

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Customer";
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDB"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
                    con.Open();
                    gvResultsDeal.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    gvResultsDeal.DataBind();

                }
```

Then you CSS needs to have the following FOR EVERY COLUMN you are calling in your SQL statement.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResultsDeal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvResultsDeal_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeader="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CUST" HeaderText="Opportunity ID" SortExpression="CUST" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS" HeaderText="DRA Instance" SortExpression="ADDRESS" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="36px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I no develop with CSS!!

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET program? or simply C#?